# How do I display UIImagePickerController non-full screen?

Tags: objective-c

In Facebook app, when you choose attach a photo, it shows the photo selection in a small popout instead of the full screen view.

How can I customise it that way? The code below create a full screen photo picker immediately.

```
   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^(){}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or use a custom container view controller to wrap your picker view controller.